# How to copy error line and few more lines to end of file in vim?

Tags: vim

I find fatal errors in my ansible log and  copy them to end of file to see all the fatal errors.

```
:g/fatal:/t$
```

But I would like to copy error and next line ,because next line some time would be 'ignoring' which need not to be considered. I can find only real fatal errors which is required

How to move pattern and few more lines? In grep we can find -A -B ,is there any way in g command to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like all ex commands inherited from `vi` and `ex`, `:help :t` can take a `:help :range`. In this case, you want to operate on the matching line and the line below, which translates to the following range:

```
.,+1
```

where:

- the left-hand side of the comma is the first line,
- the right-hand side is the last line,
- `.` represents the current line,
- `+1` represents the line below the current line,

which gives you this command:

```
:g/fatal:/.,+1t$
```

Note that `.` is implied and `+` is a shortcut for `+1`, so it can be shortened to:

```
:g/fatal:/,+t$
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: @romainl's answer is strictly better and should be preferred for what OP is trying to do.

If all you're trying to do is copy the line containing "fatal:" and a couple of lines afterward, you can do:

`/fatal:<CR>y<motion>`, where `<CR>` is <kbd>Enter</kbd> and `<motion>` can be, for example, `2j` for "this line and the next line" or `G` for "from this line to the end of the file", etc.